# Running firebase request in a foreach but want to wait for the result to proceed (async/await not working)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, react-hooks

I'm using a react useEffect hook and inside that hook I'm fetching data in a foreach from firebase nothing weird here and this seems to be working.

I want to wait for foreach and requests to finish so my array will be build and I can use it in my following code. But it seems my code is not waiting before continuing (the console.log inside the foreach is shown last in my console).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .locations()
      .once('value')
      .then(async snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          const locationObject = snapshot.val()
          const userInformation = []

          await Object.keys(locationObject).forEach(element => {
            firebase.user(element).once('value', userSnapshot => {
              if (userSnapshot.val() !== null) {
                console.log('inside location')
                userInformation.push({
                  userId: 1,
                  name: userSnapshot.val().username
                })
              }
            })
          })

          console.log('usrInfo', userInformation)
        }
      })
    })
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Object.keys(locationObject).forEach` code doesn't return a `Promise`, so calling `await` on it won't do anything.

If you want to wait for multiple promises to resolve, you'll typically want to use `Promise.all`. I'd also in general recommend using `DataSnapshot.forEach()` instead of `Object.keys().forEach()` as it maintains the order of the child nodes.

So combined that'd become something like:

```
const unsubscribe = firebase
  .locations()
  .once('value')
  .then(async snapshot => {
    let promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach(element => {
      promises.push(firebase.user(element.key).once('value'))
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).then(snapshots => {
    const userInformation = []
    snapshots.forEach(userSnapshot => {
      if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
        userInformation.push({
          userId: 1,
          name: userSnapshot.val().username
        })
      }
    })
    console.log('userInfo', userInformation)
  })
```

Comment: thanks! thank you for the nice explanation. This works perfectly!

Comment: is it also possible to pass the data from the snapshot (snapshot.val()) in the first callback to the second callback? (use data from the first.then in the second .then) pass two data sources in the return or some other way? Can't seem to get that right

Comment: The code in my answer passes all snapshots from the first `then()` to the second.

Comment: It does! But it doesn't pass the original snapshot values  (at least I think snapshots.val())which I want to use later on. Is there anyway to do that?