# useSWR is returning undefined when even though correct items print next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run a `useSWR` hook to fetch my firestore data. When I run it, it runs the `fetcher` function because the `console.log()` shows the correct item. When I try to print the data, however, it returns undefined. Is there a way to fix this? I am attaching all the code for the error.

```
const fetcher = async (location) => {
    const q = query(collection(db, location));
    const snapshot = await getDocs(q)
    let retArr = [] 
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
        retArr.push(doc.data())
    })
    return retArr
}

 function getLoc() {
     if (currentUser) {
        return 'users/' + currentUser.uid + '/userInvestments'
     } else {
        return 'users/TestDocumentForDatabase/userInvestments'
     };
 }

 const loc = getLoc();
 console.log(loc)

 const { data, error } = useSWR(
    loc,
    fetcher,
    {
       refreshInterval: 1000,
    }
 );
    
 console.log(data)
```

`getLoc` gets the location for the query, and then the fetcher is used to grab and return an array of all of the documents. This is returning undefined. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: which `console.log()` shows the correct item? And Is there any error in console?

Comment: The `console.log()` inside of the fetcher shows the correct item. There are no errors in the console. @3960278

Comment: I think the problem is in your fetcher method. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160161/running-firebase-request-in-a-foreach-but-want-to-wait-for-the-result-to-proceed

Comment: You need to add conditional logic to check if your data is still loading. [`data`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/api#return-values) returns `undefined` until the data has finished loading. See [SWR's basic usage example](https://swr.vercel.app/examples/basic)

Comment: I added ```{error && <p>Theres an error</p>} {data && <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>}``` to my code and all it shows is there is an error. That means there is an issue with actually fetching the data. @koolskateguy89